# MS SQL Server 2008 changing inserted row value in trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

In Oracle i can change the row value by :new.column_name = new_value in insert/update trigger. 
How can I do the same in MS SQL 2008 Trigger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike `Oracle`, affected records are passed in sets to `SQL Server` triggers, referenced to as `INSERTED` and `DELETED`.

You will have to update the target table:

```
UPDATE   m
SET      column_name = @new_value
FROM     INSERTED i
JOIN     mytable m
ON       m.id = i.id
```

or, better, create an `INSTEAD OF` trigger.